# Subscribe on Events by Event name prefix using Symfony EventDispatcher

Tags: php, event-handling, symfony

Is it possible to listen all events by their name prefixes?

For example we have event `kernel.componentName.eventName`

Can I listen to any events with prefix `kernel.componentName.*` or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in multiple ways. One of them is to call `EventDispatcher#getListeners` without any argument, get a list of all the  event names that start with `kernel.componentName.` and subscribe to them one by one.

I think that the simpler way is to extends `EventDispatcher`.

```
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;

class MyEventDispatcher extends EventDispatcher
{
    protected function doDispatch($listeners, $eventName, Event $event)
    {
        // add logic here
        if (strpos($eventName, 'kernel.componentName.') === 0) {
            // do something, like call another listener or a callback
        }


        parent::doDispatch($listeners, $eventName, $event);
    }
}
```